# How to display only header of grouped rows in Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

If I have a data in data source like these

```
      ___Main Item___|___Sub Item____|______QTY____
              A      |      aa       |        3
              A      |      aa       |        2       
              A      |      ab       |        1
              B      |      bb       |        7
```

So I have to grouped with "Main Item" and "Sub Item"
and Sum "Value"

I need to display only one item from grouped items
 and display summation of them.       Like these

```
               aa       5   pcs
               ab       1   pcs                 
               bb       7   pcs
```

I tried to added group in tablix and create groped header.
By these step

[image]

> 1. Drag **"SUB_ITEM"** and **"QTY"** Columns to tablix
> 2. Create group with adding *header group*.
> 3. Hide  **"SUB_ITEM"** and **"QTY"** columns

But It isn't ok, Rows was hidden make line space.
If some Item has many repeat rows it will make a more space.

[image]

What shold I do?

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry. I just delete instead hidden.
So I just do like these

> 1 Drag "SUB_ITEM" and "QTY" Columns to tablix
>
> 2.Create group with adding header group.
>
> 3.**Delete**   "SUB_ITEM" and "QTY"  row.